# Angularjs: Why does adding an authorization header cause a -1 status response?

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, http-post, restier

I have a pre-existing angular code that gets data from an API. I'm trying to add an authentication token to the request.

To begin with I tried a simple example

```
.factory('getDep', [
        '$resource', function($resource) {
            return $resource('/ContactsDatabaseAPI/deps/:id', { id: '@id' }, {
                query: {
                    method: 'GET',
                    isArray: false,
                    headers: {
                        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
                    }
                },
                create: {
                    method: 'POST'
                },
                update: {
                    method: 'PUT'
                },
                remove: {
                    method: 'DELETE'
                }
            });
        }
```

When the GET call is fired, and F12-ing in Chrome, I get an error message of:

```
angular.js:11821 OPTIONS http://localhost:56057/ContactsDatabaseAPI/deps net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

The return status of -1 and no sign of the call making it to the server side.

Without the headers line, it works fine.

If I try the GET call in **Postman** with the same Authorization value in the header, this also works fine.

I've also tried to add the header in the httpInterceptor and get the same result:

```
config.headers = config.headers || {};
config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + authData.token;
```

Other things I've tried:

- A random header name causes the same issue.
- I've added **'Content-Type' = 'text/plain; charset=utf-8'** as a header. This has no change to the result

I'm using angular 1.5.6

Comment: what is your backend?

Comment: Using Restier (https://github.com/OData/RESTier) Basically Web API 2 written in .net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved my issue and thanks to @Mourad-Idrissi for pointing me in the right direction.

The reason it worked before is that there was no Pre-Flight checks before the API was run. When I added the header, this changed the way the client communicated to the API. Now there was a OPTIONS call to the API which was causing the error. As the domain was different, this introduced me to the world of CORS.

By adding the following to my Application_BeginRequest() method in my backend Web API, Pre-flight now passes and my application continues.

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this (in the controller) :

$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token;

Comment: We use a couple of different APIs in the application. I believe adding this will mean the token is attached to all API calls.

Comment: it does the same thing as what written, the difference is that you forced the http header. (you can use it on each call of service)

Comment: I gave it a go anyway. I get the same error message

Comment: are you using oauth ? or your own API ? (make sure of the OPTIONS and GET requests on the server side)